# Can I remove *-dev packages if I'm not compiling apps from source code?

Tags: debian, package-management, development

I rarely compile source code myself and mostly install stuff using apt-get.  So, can I safely uninstall all those *-dev files?  Or are some apps reliant on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should be safe to remove any `*-dev` packages, since these are typically the header files needed when compiling against a give packaged library. Remember you can always list the contents of a given package using `dpkg -L <pkg>` if you have any doubts as to what's inside it.

#### Example

```
$ dpkg -L libgdbm-dev | head -10
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/dbm.h
/usr/include/gdbm.h
/usr/include/gdbm-ndbm.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.a
```